# Laravel singleton not working across controller/ViewComposer

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection, ioc-container, php-5.6

In Laravel, I have a class that I would like to make available to the service controller, make some changes to in the controller action, and then render out with a ViewComposer.

I have done this several times before without issue, but for some reason this time my usual approach is not working - clearly I'm doing something different, and I'm beginning to suspect I've fundamentally misunderstood an aspect of what I am doing.

I have a ServiceProvider with this register() method:

```
public function register()
{
    $this->app->singleton(HelperTest::class, function ($app) {
        $pb = new HelperTest();

        $pb->test = "jokes on you batman";

        return $pb;
    });
}
```

Then in my controller I'm doing the following:

```
private $helper;

public function __construct(HelperTest $pb)
{
    $this->helper = $pb;
    $this->helper->test = "hahah";
}
```

And then I have a viewcomposer doing the following:

```
private $helper;

public function __construct(HelperTest $pb)
{
    $this->helper = $pb;
}

public function compose(View $view)
{
    $view->with('output', $this->helper->test);
}
```

When I call `{{ $output }}` in the blade view, I expect to see `hahah`, but instead I get `jokes on you batman`.

My debugging has shown that all three of these methods are definitely being called. It looks to me like the ViewComposer is for some reason instantiating its own, fresh instance of the class. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: I've done a bit more debugging and it appears that compose() is being called BEFORE the controller action. Why would that be???

Answer (score 1):

Execute `php artisan optimize` on your console, this will generate an optimized class loader for your application, then check if you can find your class `HelperTest` registered in `services.php` inside `boostrap/cache`. Until `HelperTest` is not registered there, Laravel IoC can't resolve your class.